# Avoiding duplicate signals in Django when editing many_to_many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I want automatically update an external application about a change in a model. The problem is that the data is in a many2many relation between events **<->** users. I tried to use the ["m2m_changed" signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Event.organisers.through)
def event_changed(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if "post" in action:
      # hey api here is the new list of organisers of this
```

**The problem with this is that if i make a single change where i remove one user and add another then this code is called twice!** That's no good and i can't just ignore one type of operation in case only that operation is called. I have thought pushing instances to stacks and ignoring dups but that seems messy. Is there a way i can make my own signal that only fires once?

Comment: Can't you make your code idempotent so that calling it twice does not harm?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña then the only way to be sure there was a change would be to ask the formentioned api. Using an api for what should be an internal function would surely add some code debt. If you have a clever way how I could let it be called twice with out sending 2 post I am all ears :)

Comment: Try the `dispatch_uid` approach as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: @LorenzoPeña I tried it but that seems to only solve the problem if your signal connector is run a number of times.

Comment: Can you afford Django 1.9 where there is a related method `set()` that does it all in one?

Comment: Yes found out about this just today thanks, but i think i found a more robust way to do this by doing a db query based on a last modified field (from last push till now) a small delay is fine for what i am doing and possibly even wanted if a user were to make a bunch of quick edits.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then, for future reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't relay seem to be a good answer to this question so here is some useful workarounds that are better than what i was imagined in the first pace.

## Solution 1:

Instead of combining signals instead add the primary keys of the instances to a set to ignore duplicate signals:

```
updated = set()

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Event.organisers.through) 
def event_changed(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
        if "post" in action:
          updated.add(instance.pk)

def send_updates():
    for Event in updated:              # Iteration AKA for each element
       #update code here
```

While this requires some sort of scheduled task to run send_updates() it avoids the chance of spamming if there are many consecutive changes to the event.

## Solution 2

Ignore signals altogether add last modified to the model. Then run a query to get all events between now and when the send_updates() was last called. Store the last called somewhere to disk/database to avoid having to resend everything on restart.

Answer (score 5):

Django `m2m_changed` indicates change on ManyToMany model. If has 4 actions

1. pre_add
2. post_add
3. pre_remove
4. post_remove

So if you're just adding a user, this m2m_changed method would be triggered 2 times, for `pre_add` and `post_add` respectively.

You can specify at which action you want to call API. This could be done as:

```
    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Event.organisers.through)
    def event_changed(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('action') == 'pre_add': # Or whatever action you want
       # Call your API here
```

Reference Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed